# Calling a function upon contact with barrier, but not colliding. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode7, uicollisionbehavior

I would like to know if it is possible to call a function when a UIView comes into contact with a collision boundary, but not to have them actually collide.

Can a function be called when they come into contact and have the view go right through the boundary?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `UIKit` framework provides a nice collision detection facility.

To respond to UIKit *dynamic item* collisions (e.g., views) configure a custom class to adopt the `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate` protocol. Then, in a collision behavior (an instance of the `UICollisionBehavior` class), set the delegate to be an instance of your custom class.

In the aforementioned `UICollisionBehavior` add your view to it and configure your desired boundary using one of the `addBoundary` methods. Your delegate will then be notified of a collision in the `collisionBehavior(_:beganContactFor:withBoundaryIdentifier:at:)` protocol function.

(The default `collisionMode` is `everything`, so you can safely ignore this property for now.)

Comment: Very nice. Now, will the view actually collide and stop upon contact with the boundary?

Comment: @willThatBeAll No, it shouldn't stop. The actual *collision response*, if any, is up to you :-)